# How can I make lynx to associate magnet: links with aria2c?

Tags: lynx, magnet, magnet-links, aria2

I use lynx, but everytime I need to open a `magnet:` link I need to save it and then, get out of lynx and then `cat lynx_bookmarks.html` copy the link  and the pass it to the command line as a parameter to `aria2c`.

How can I associate the `magnet:` links to aria2c so that lynx knows to open them with `aria2c` by defaul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lynx will not do this for you; the "magnet:" URI is not recognized.  See the documentation for known protocols: http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/lynx_url_support.html